# select from where field not equal to field in other table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am running the following script in SQLite3:

```
drop table if exists B;
drop table if exists C;

create table B (a integer, b text, c text);

insert into B values (1, "1.1", "B");
insert into B values (1, "2.1", "B");
insert into B values (3, "3.1", "B");
insert into B values (4, "4.1", "B");
insert into B values (5, "5.1", "B");
insert into B values (6, "6.1", "B");
insert into B values (7, "7.1", "B");

create table C (a integer);

insert into C (a) values (1), (3), (5);

select * from B where B.a <> C.a;
```

This script throws an error when I run it:

> Error: near line 30: no such column: C.a

The idea here is that I would like to make a selection from `B` where field `a` is *not* equal to 1, 3 or 5. Is it not possible to refer to columns from other tables within the same SQL statement? How to achieve this?

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
a|b|c
4|"4.1"|"B"
6|"6.1"|"B"
7|"7.1"|"B"
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM B WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT a FROM C)`

Comment: That seems to work...Do you know whether this query can be built in Microsoft Access?

Comment: It's standard SQL but I don't use MS Access to know for sure.

Comment: Why don't you post your comment as an answer? I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: On a side note: The standard delimiter for string literals is the single quote (`'`), not the double quote (`"`). The double quotes are for alias names containing special characters (e.g. `select count(*) as "number of rows" from ...`). In certain situations you can get unwanted results when confusing the two (e.g.: `where key = "description"` would compare the content of the column key with the content of the column description, and not with the string 'description', if a column with that name exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requirement can be expressed with `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
select * from B 
where not exists (
  select 1 from C
  where C.a = B.a
);
```

For every row of `B` if `B.a` does not exist in `C` then `NOT EXISTS` is `TRUE` and that row is returned.

Or with a `LEFT JOIN` from which only the unmatched rows of `B` are returned:

```
select B.*
from B left join C
on C.a = B.a
where C.a is null;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2oGuNXwzfCK43CNb5fS9U/0).
Results:

```
| a   | b   | c   |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4   | 4.1 | B   |
| 6   | 6.1 | B   |
| 7   | 7.1 | B   |
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM B WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM C)`

This is standard SQL.

`NOT IN` excludes all values from the selected set.  The set can be from another table, not necessarily a list of constant values.

`DISTINCT` is optional but it may produce faster execution in very large sets.

Comment: It is generally *not* recommended using `DISTINCT` with `IN`. SQL is meant to express what we want, not how the DBMS shall achieve this. In this case we want all B rows the A value of which is not in the set of C's A values. Whether the DBMS uses `DISTINCT` on the set to do this or not, should be left to itself. It usually knows best how to look up data.

Comment: `IN` and `NOT IN` refer to sets.  Sets are by definition made of distinct values.  However, SQL engines can not always know the inner `SELECT` will be used as a set to automatically do the `DISTINCT` for you.  In any case, it certainly does not hurt, only helps if at all.  (Do you have some reference as to the "not recommended" and why?)